docker build fails while docker pull works as expected
I trying to build a jenkins image starting FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts and it fails with error: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io
If I run docker build .
docker build  .
[+] Building 30.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.49kB                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts                                                                                         30.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts
   2 |
   3 |     ADD --chown=1000:1000 plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts: failed to authorize: DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Ajenkins%2Fjenkins%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp 54.196.99.49:443: i/o timeout

If I run docker pull all is good:
docker pull jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts
2.440.1-lts: Pulling from jenkins/jenkins
7bb465c29149: Pull complete
c18f106040a7: Pull complete
f826d0f09907: Pull complete
bc3128b515a7: Pull complete
45dc40627eb2: Pull complete
ce448981c34b: Pull complete
f2e0835aa94f: Pull complete
bce8503d6e45: Pull complete
3353a3a64a1f: Pull complete
5b9963212983: Pull complete
0a769ec2c083: Pull complete
6bbf8192cfe6: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:01c0b0cf789fa24253090fccea264df223b5e09b14a0ea59f0847c70bdc0f31c
Status: Downloaded newer image for jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts
docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts

If I run docker build AFTER docker pull the build process is good since the image is already present locally.
docker build  .
[+] Building 2.4s (12/13)                                                                                                                                   docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.49kB                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [1/9] FROM docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts                                                                                                                  0.2s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 6.94kB                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [2/9] ADD --chown=1000:1000 plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/                                                                                                        0.0s

docker info
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    27.3.1
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.17.1
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.29.7
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

The environment is: no direct internet connection, only through a proxy. It looks like docker build does not respect the Environment set at /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf. This config is respected by docker pull.
The DNS works as expected (so docker run also knows how to download an image which is not present locally):
docker run --rm busybox nslookup docker.io
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
2fce1e0cdfc5: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c230832bd3b0be59a6c47ed64294f9ce71e91b327957920b6929a0caa8353140
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
Server:         172.16.0.2
Address:        172.16.0.2:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   docker.io
Address: 3.224.227.198
Name:   docker.io
Address: 44.219.3.189
Name:   docker.io
Address: 44.193.181.103

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   docker.io
Address: 2600:1f18:2148:bc02:4f78:625e:1ac1:714c
Name:   docker.io
Address: 2600:1f18:2148:bc01:2822:9e2a:c82a:af0
Name:   docker.io
Address: 2600:1f18:2148:bc00:a518:1574:fea8:ccdb

I even tried to put proxy IP addresses instead FQDNs same issue. The same error can be found in jounalctl -u docker.service. Same error happens if I add/use /etc/docker/daemon.json.
I tried adding this docker client config but still no luck:
cat ~/.docker/config.json
{
 "proxies": {
   "default": {
     "httpProxy": "http://proxy.domain.internal:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "http://proxy.domain.internal:3129",
     "noProxy": "*.domain.internal,127.0.0.1"
   }
 }
}

I also tried this hack with docker buildx create --use --driver-opt:
docker buildx create --use --driver-opt env.http_proxy=http://proxy.domain.internal:3128 --driver-opt env.https_proxy=http://proxy.domain.internal:3128 --driver-opt '"env.no_proxy='*.domain.internal,127.0.0.1'"'
inspiring_matsumoto

docker buildx build .
[+] Building 35.7s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                                                     docker-container:inspiring_matsumoto
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                       5.2s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                    4.6s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_inspiring_matsumoto0                                                                                                        0.6s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.49kB                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts                                                                                         30.3s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts:
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile:1

I also tried this and still same error:
docker build --build-arg HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.domain.internal:3128 \
--build-arg HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.domain.internal:3128 --build-arg NO_PROXY="*.domain.internal,127.0.0.1" \
--build-arg http_proxy=http://proxy.domain.internal:3128 --build-arg https_proxy=http://proxy.domain.internal:3128 \
--build-arg no_proxy="*.domain.internal,127.0.0.1" 
[+] Building 30.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                           docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.49kB                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts                                                                                         30.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts
   2 |
   3 |     ADD --chown=1000:1000 plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: DeadlineExceeded: jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts: failed to authorize: DeadlineExceeded: failed to fetch anonymous token: Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Ajenkins%2Fjenkins%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": dial tcp 54.196.99.49:443: i/o timeout

I tried all the above with the IP address of the proxy (not the FQDN) and receive the same error. Did even docker system prune -a, systemctl restart docker, rebooted the instance and docker build --no-cache just to have a clean env and Again docker pull works! docker build does not respect the proxy settings.
I also tried to create a custom builder but there is no way to specify the proxy just a mirror to docker.io repo. This attempt is trying to find endpoint /v2/jenkins... on the proxy URL. I don’t have a mirror of docker.io locally on the proxy instance. I want docker buildx to use the proxy settings same as docker pull.
cat /etc/buildkitd.toml
debug = true
[registry."docker.io"]
mirrors = ["http://proxy.domain.internal:3128"]

docker buildx create --use --bootstrap \
--name mybuilder \
--driver docker-container \
--config /etc/buildkitd.toml
[+] Building 1.8s (1/1) FINISHED
 => [internal] booting buildkit                                                                                                                                       1.8s
 => => pulling image moby/buildkit:buildx-stable-1                                                                                                                    0.9s
 => => creating container buildx_buildkit_mybuilder0                                                                                                                  0.9s
mybuilder

docker buildx ls
NAME/NODE        DRIVER/ENDPOINT                   STATUS    BUILDKIT   PLATFORMS
mybuilder*       docker-container
 \_ mybuilder0    \_ unix:///var/run/docker.sock   running   v0.16.0    linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
default          docker
 \_ default       \_ default                       running   v0.16.0    linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386

docker buildx --builder mybuilder build .
[+] Building 30.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                               docker-container:mybuilder
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.49kB                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts                                                                                         30.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts:
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts
   2 |
   3 |     ADD --chown=1000:1000 plugins.txt /var/jenkins_home/
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts: failed to resolve source metadata for docker.io/jenkins/jenkins:2.440.1-lts: failed to do request: Head "https://proxy.domain.internal:3128/v2/jenkins/jenkins/manifests/2.440.1-lts?ns=docker.io": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client

while browsing through this (thanks BMitch) I found that Client-side token fetching can be disabled by defining BUILDKIT_NO_CLIENT_TOKEN=1. Added this made it work. It's a workaround but it works.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/cli/proxy/

did that, same error, I edited my question

Your proxy setting is wrong, the https proxy should still have http:// (no s), which explains the error show (http response to https request).

It checked my code and it was a typo here since I have to replace the correct subdomain.domain. So even without the s in https:// it still does not work

--driver-opt env.http_proxy=http//proxy.domain.internal:3128 there's a colon missing after http.

While I'm pretty sure this is supported with the correct configuration, there are some open issues in GitHub that may be related: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues?q=is%3Aissue+https_proxy

http// also a typo, still doesn't work. Buuuut while browsing through the issues in the link you provided I found this gem: if you set this BUILDKIT_NO_CLIENT_TOKEN=1 it works. so thanks!
